# Why is memcpy not copying the data I give to it?

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

I'm making a memory manager/allocator in C++. The function "memcpy" doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the offending code:

```
template <class Type>
Data<Type> MemoryManager::alloc(Type* data) {
    ...
    printf("Allocating data of size %i at local address %i, absolute address %i\n", allocSize, allocAddress, allocStart + allocAddress);
    ...
    std::cout << *data << std::endl;
    memcpy(data, (Type*)(allocStart + allocAddress), allocSize);
    std::cout << *(Type*)(allocStart + allocAddress) << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

For a test, I tried allocating an integer with a value of 20. What gets outputted to standard output when I run this test is this:

```
Allocating data of size 4 at local address 0, absolute address 16834208
20
-842150451
```

As you can see, `data` (which is a pointer to a `Type`) is pointing to the correct value of 20 when I attempt to dereference. However, after using memcpy to copy to the new address (also a pointer to a `Type`), the value has become -842150451. What's interesting is that it's always this number, no matter what I test with, no matter what the actual address ends up being. Also, this number is not the minimum value for an integer on my system - as you can see, the size of an integer is 4 bytes. So what is this number? And why does memcpy always copy it into my address instead of the data I've given it?

EDIT: I had the arguments in the wrong order. Problem solved. But my second question remains, what is that number, and why is it always copied in no matter what my source is?

Comment: `memcpy`'s first argument is destination, not source.

Comment: Any type of object with copy-semantics (copy-construction, copy-assignment) will not be copyable with a bytewise mechanism like `std::memcpy`.

Comment: Concerning `memcpy()`: Are you aware that the first argument is _destination_ and the second is _source_? From your snippet, I believe you tried to use them swapped. [memcpy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)

Comment: Also, if you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. Always use C++ casts, like e.g. `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Yep I had the arguments in the wrong order. But to be honest the more interesting question to me was the second part, what is -842150451? It was ALWAYS this number being copied, no matter what actual address was the source

Comment: `memcpy(d, s, len);` follows the same parameter ordering as `d = s;` ... which is typical of many of the routines in the the standard C library and the Unix API.  Destination parameters first, source parameter latter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, why is that? What's the benefit in this case?

Comment: Also, if you continue to use `printf` instead of the type-safe `std::cout` and `<<` operators, then you need to be very specific with the formatting codes to make sure it really matches the argument type. Like for example to print a `size_t` you should be using `%zu`. To print a `void *` pointer (and yes a cast is needed to be correct) you should use the `%p` format.

Comment: A C-style cast is just a way to silence the compiler. It basically says to the compiler "don't bother me with this", which can lead to UB if the cast turns out to be wrong (like breaking strict aliasing).

Comment: The decimal value you are seeing is hexadecimasl CDCDCDCD. Some platform use it to mark uninitialized memory

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the printfs and couts were just for debugging, but thanks for the tip

Comment: @bambarbiyakergudu C++ style casts (static_cast, etc.) is checked by compiler, thus will help with detecting errors at compile time, and possibly prevent runtime errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure that "A C-style cast is just a way to silence the compiler" is quite true, it tells the compiler to treat the object as if it were whatever you're casting it to, and in the case of a pointer that's exactly what I want... is it not? I don't want any reinterpretation, it should be the same value treated differently

Comment: @MathiasJ Alright, I can accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First Argument should be Destination and second should be source
Like This :

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

A simple example :

```
char myname[] = "Pierre de Fermat";
/* using memcpy to copy string: */
memcpy ( person.name, myname, sizeof(myname) );
```

Comment: Could use `sizeof(myname)` at compile time instead of `strlen(myname)+1` at run time.

Comment: Yeah You're Right, sizeof() will be O(1)